# How to match data_receipt to transaction?

Tags: nearprotocol

For example we have: data_receipt with id = `Ft9SKhvk7YTgMtZBQt741RHRpF9GDtrVUXbm7Txr1GYK`

This receipt we can find only in chunk. We can easily match it with block, but not with transactions.

Transactions does not have data_receipt.

Can anyone explain how I can match it with transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how it work [near indexer github](https://github.com/near/near-indexer-for-explorer/blob/14391b4a30c7082cedaa2717a0c2efaf9ebc0cdd/src/db_adapters/receipts.rs)

```
if let Some(transaction_hash) = 
            tx_hashes_for_receipts.get(&receipt_or_data_id) {
            Some(models::Receipt::from_receipt_view(
                    r,
                    block_hash,
                    transaction_hash,
                    chunk_hash,
                    index as i32,
                    block_timestamp,
                ))
        }
```

It's mean that receipt is data, receipt have data_id in core of tree. And some transaction have receipt with field  data_id included to output_data_receivers

data_id from output_data_receivers equal to data_id from data_receipt

data receipt: `Ft9SKhvk7YTgMtZBQt741RHRpF9GDtrVUXbm7Txr1GYK` with data_id : `HWCSA1gNd7NviQ4ZmqNZ7P6fy5RA93NGbXjmQSNWpJxc`

```
{
   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
   "id": "dontcare",
   "method": "chunk",
   "params": {
     "chunk_id": "DBTgMT3NMnkof9pX5Lg1dZvfBB6REJD3vibEQThkjnWe"
    }
}
```

transaction getting in parsing process: `EToG7FhgJyDBg1VbFhyRSSxYTZ9SGPjy1tVnbBTPbdth` this transaction have receipt : `5VDF57ehUt43oZ2yfULj8QL9wR9aojEXUkjD4XQB7rj2`

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": "dontcare",
"method": "EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status",
"params": [
    "EToG7FhgJyDBg1VbFhyRSSxYTZ9SGPjy1tVnbBTPbdth",
    "9nearapps.near"
    ]
}
```

this receipt have output_data_receivers and in tree have data_id: `HWCSA1gNd7NviQ4ZmqNZ7P6fy5RA93NGbXjmQSNWpJxc`

```
"output_data_receivers": [
    {
    "data_id": "HWCSA1gNd7NviQ4ZmqNZ7P6fy5RA93NGbXjmQSNWpJxc",
    "receiver_id": "v1.nearapps.near"
    }
]
```

Ps. Sorry for my english